# Error in uploading image and text file to server using php

Tags: php, html, forms

> PHP FILE  :
>   This is my form action file in php.
>   I am successful in uploading images but text files are producing 'Invalid File Error'.
>   What may be the error and how to resolve it?

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "txt");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/txt"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
  else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
  }
else
  {
     echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider changing $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/txt"  to  $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain" also what do you get when you print $_FILES["file"]["type"] for text files ?

Comment: Yeah you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think your mime type for .txt files is correct. You could try `txt/plain` instead of `txt/text` in your IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain"
```

Instead of

```
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/txt"
```

Here is the list of [mime-content-type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).